# Common Vendor.bundle.js for 2 Angular Apps

Tags: angular, webpack

Is it possible for 2 angular apps to share a common vendor.bundle.js (included in index.html of both apps)? The vendor.ts have similar content for both the apps.

vendor.ts

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/animations';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
```

I want my two applications to use the same vendor.bundle.js file so that the browser can cache the vendor file and load time of the application can be improved for the second application user browse through

Comment: This is a brilliant idea.